# NTLM аутентификация в .NET CORE

Tags: .net, windows, asp.net-core, .net-core

В общем, хочу добавить NTLM аутентификацию.

[Тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) я вычитал что Kestrel с недавних пор поддерживает эту возможность и нужно лишь поставить вот этот пакет:

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate)

Я все поставил и сделал, как там написано:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();
```

и 
    app.UseAuthentication();

Запускаю свое API приложение на Windows и стучусь в контроллер Google Chrome с этого же ПК.

Мне вылетает сообщение о том, что я должен ввести учетные данные. Я ввожу учетные данные домена в котором находится мой ПК, но ничего не происходит и меня их снова спрашивают.

Что я упустил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, что нужно было добавить `app.UseAuthentication();`, хотя сервер `UseHttpSys` работал без этого.